# How to binarize textual data with scikit learn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am vectorizing some textual data with scikit's tfidf. By the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) I read that that you can set idf and normalization to False to get 0/1 outputs(binary feature vector?). So I tried the following:

```
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False,
                            smooth_idf=True,
                            sublinear_tf=False,
                            ngram_range=(2,2),
                            norm=False)
```

With this the feature vector will be binary?. By the other hand in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#binarization) there is another module that can do this task, Preprocessing. Any idea of how to aproach this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TfidfVectorizer` take a parameter called `binary`:

```
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False,binary=True, norm=False, ngram_range=(2, 2))
```

This will make the features binary